# Java invoking implementation of interface method which has Object args

Tags: java

I have a Java interface which expects variable input argument of type Object.

```
public interface TestInterface <I,O>{
   public O invoke(I...inputs);
}

public class FirstClass implements TestInterface<String, Object>{
        @Override
    public Object invoke( String... input ){
        System.out.println("inside VO");
        return "Tet";
    }
}
```

Main class where I'm trying to invoke this.

```
   public class Main{
        public static void main( String[] args ){
            FirstClass voDS=new FirstClass();
            TestInterface ds=voDS;
            ds.invoke( "abc" );
        }
    }
```

When I invoke this, I get `ClassCast Exception Object not compatible with String error`. Is there any workaround using which I can invoke this?

Comment: Your example gives no errors when compiled with Java 7.

Comment: I don't get any compilation error. It is runtime exception. I use Java 6.

Comment: So which line is giving the error?

Comment: @Kayaman             ds.invoke( "abc" );
 line

Comment: I'm confirming the runtime exception in Java 7, but there's a specific reason why...

Comment: Can you please let me know the reason? Also is there any workaround to invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I can give you an answer, you'll have to agree with me on this point of orthography first:

This snippet:

```
FirstClass voDS = new FirstClass();
TestInterface ds = voDS;
ds.invoke("abc");
```

...is equivalent to:

```
TestInterface voDS = new FirstClass();
voDS.invoke("abc");
```

It's a pattern used when creating collections; the interface is used as opposed to the concrete class.

With that out of the way, let's observe a curious property about the interface:

```
public O invoke(I...inputs);
```

Hey, that's a type parameter, isn't it?  The type `I` is associated with the declaration `TestInterface<I, O>`.  That means we expect something of a generic type `I` when we're using the interface abstraction.

Now, we come to the concrete implementation...it doesn't share the same generic bounds!

```
public class FirstClass implements TestInterface<String, Object>
```

Uh-oh.  Due to type erasure, we're going to get a raw type if we try to use this as our concrete implementation, and we'll *likely* get a `ClassCastException` with the vararg array.

The fix is simple:  **use your concrete types when declaring an instance of your interface with respect to your backing class.**

```
TestInterface<String, Object> voDS = new FirstClass();
voDS.invoke("abc");
```

Now, your interface knows what type of parameter it should expect in the varargs field, and what it should return.

Now this isn't an *ideal* use of generics - in many cases, you would have to provide the generic types to your backing class to get it to work properly.